# Material icons not showing on a hosted webpages

Tags: html, css, materialize

I hosted a site on Github pages, and the material icons are not showing. The issue is that they are showing when I launch the index.html page from my browser (instead of going to the hosted page).

[image: What I get from the page on my computer]

[image: What I get from the hosted page]

Here's the html for this part:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content blue-text text-darken-2">
            <span class="card-title">Olivier Grech</span>
            <p>Text</p>
            <div><i class="material-icons">phone</i><em>Phone</em></div>
                <div><a href="mailto:mail"><i class="material-icons">email</i></a><em>mail</em></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--Rest of the page-->
```

Comment: The icon code is <i class="material-icons">phone</i> without other text. Maybe is this the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `http` with `https` and it will work:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you open your developer tools(right click anywhere and click `inspect`, then go to the console), it would tell you whats wrong. In this case you were accessing the github page over **https** but were trying to load the font using **http** which is not considered safe and was blocked by the browser.

Comment: That was it, thanks! And thanks for the insight too.